# How exactly are the numbers returned from DragEvent's getX() and getY() methods?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

`DragEvent` is a class thats used with the Drag and Drop api from Android. 2 of its methods to be specific, `getX()` and `getY()` are of particular importance. I would like to know exactly over what part of a `View` another View thats being dragged over is at.

For example, in my case, its very important to know if a user drags, say a TextView over another TextView, but I need to know if its closer to the bottom half, or the top half. Issue is, I have no idea how those numbers are used in relation to screen placement. I appreciate any help on this matter.

Edit: Hopefully I was clear what I am asking. If any clarification needs to be given, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

getX() and getY() methods return the coordinates relative to the target view on which you need to drop. You can test this by using Toasts as follows:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "X:" + (int)event.getX() + ", Y:" + (int)event.getY(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

When I tested it, my target view was starting from half down of the screen. On dropping a view on the starting edge of this target view, the toast message showed getY() value around 1.